# Where I start from making android messaging app?

Tags: android

Please suggest me. I am a new android programmer. I want to create a messaging app for chat with friends. Please give me the proper way to achieve messaging in my application.

Comment: go to playstore, download a messaging app (e.g. whatsapp) and start messaging with your friends. This is the fastest and easiest way. ;)

Comment: I think he wants to create a messaging app, not do chatting with friends.:)

Comment: @Aakash you are definitely right aakash...but sometimes I am mean

Comment: guys i want to create an app for my personal messaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Any server-side programming language
2. Java for android development
3. A strong understanding on JSON parsing
4. Take help from Google Cloud Messaging(GCM) Tool
5. Understanding XMPP and XMPP Server

For creating an instant messaging app, you need to have knowledge on front-end development which is taken care by Android system. For storing data to servers, back-end language is needed (I prefer PHP). For sending data back and forth, JSON will help with that. GCM will provide you with push notification services.

Here is a easy way to start creating an Chatting application

*Using GCM:*

https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/

*Using XMPP:*

You can use QuickBlox for free.

It provides XMPP server out of the box with lots of features, you can read about features there http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat

Here is an example how to start using QuickBlox with aSmack library http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

You can also build your own XMPP server in conjunction with server-side programming language

Comment: I downvoted because this question is way too broad and we shouldn't be encouraging people to ask this kind of question by answering them. We should be flagging or voting to close them, depending on your rep level.

Comment: @skrrgwasme - ok, you are right,in future I will keep in mind..

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following ways to achieve messaging in your application:

1. Google Cloud Messaging
2. Parse.com
3. QuickBlox and many more

You can find much more information regarding these on the below links:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

https://parse.com/

https://quickblox.com/